# how to scale child div without getting out of the shape of parent div in css?

Tags: css

I want to scale the child more than the parent without getting out of the boundary of the parent.

[image]
to
[image]

Like this

Comment: Have you tried anything? For example overflow?

Comment: No I new to css

Comment: Than you have an answer above. And read any basic CSS tutorial please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `overflow: hidden` to your parent div.

For example:

```css
.parent {
  width: 90%;
  heigth: 80%;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  width: 120%;
  heigth: 120%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 parent...
 <div class="child">
 child...
 </div>
 </div>
```